# Magento 2 Add Button in Edit Product page and land back there after POST request

Tags: magento2, products, admin-controller, router, custom-button

So, as the title says, I want to add an Admin button in the Edit Product Admin page. That button, when pressed, will call the respective controller of a URL, sending along the product id, the Controller will do *something* with it, and when the operation is done I want to land back in the specific product's Edit Product page, optionally together with a completion message.

This is the file `view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="update" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">update</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Price</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mymodule/priceupdate/update</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

This is my `etc\adminhtml\routes.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
            <module name="MyCompany_MyModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And this is the `Controller\Adminhtml\PriceUpdate\UpdateAction.php` file:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\PriceUpdate;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class UpdateAction extends Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{

    /**
     * Undocumented variable
     *
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $json = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $messages = [];
        $error = false;

        return $json->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

For start, the file is as it is to have it do nothing (just get called and return to Product Edit Page) and when that goes ok, I will add the functionality. This however fails, redirecting me to the Dashboard with a message saying `Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.`. The structure I used for the `UpdateAction` came from a tutorial I did on Magento. The Button appears fine.

Any help about how I will achieve the desired functionality, or at least how the non-functional request will work so as to then search further, is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, set path back to referrer:

```
...
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

class...
{ 
   ...
   private $redirect;

   public function __construct(
      ...
      RedirectInterface $redirect
   ) {
      ...
      $this->redirect = $redirect;
   }

   public function execute()
   {
      ...
      
      return $resultRedirect->setPath($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
   }

   ...
}
```